# HTML 2 color background + repeated image?

Tags: html, repeat

I made a html page with css

http://tulyita.hu/Website/

How can I put a background image (tulyita.hu/Website/images/background.png)center with repeat-x?

css code: http://tulyita.hu/Website/website.css

Comment: What is the problem exacly? your image seems to ba acting the way you want no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body{ background:url("tulyita.hu/Website/images/background.png") repeat-x center top; }
```